# how can i nest <input> tag within <label> tag in html?

Tags: html

est an input element within each label. Be sure to add each input after the label text, and include a space after the colon.

```
    <form>
             <label>Enter Your First Name:</label>
             
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly valid HTML to nest an input inside a label.

```
<label>First Name:
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
</label>
```

You don't need the `for` and `id` attributes in these cases as they are implied by the markup.

Comment: it dosn't work , i'm solving a task on freecodecamp , they ask me to nest <input> (Nest an input element within each label. Be sure to add each input after the label text, and include a space after the colon.) where this colon?!!!!!!!

Comment: this is code:           <fieldset>
        <label>Enter Your First Name:  </label>
        
        <label>Enter Your Last Name: </label>
        
        <label>Enter Your Email:  </label>
        
        <label>Create a New Password:  </label>
        
      </fieldset>

Comment: The colon is the two dots after each string. So I guess they want something like: <fieldset><label>Enter Your First Name: <input /></label> <label>Enter Your Last Name: <input /></label> <label>Enter Your Email: <input /></label> <label>Create a New Password: <input /></label> </fieldset>

Comment: dosen't work also

Comment: https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/what-should-i-do-nest-an-input-element-within-each-label-be-sure-to-add-each-input-after-the-label-text-and-include-a-space-after-the-colon/511894

Answer (score -2):

Here is the Way

```
<label for="firstName"></label>
<input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
```

Always Remember
The Value ID of the Input element and the Value of For in Label element should be same.

Comment: The question states that they wish to *nest* the input inside the label.